# Isocategorical groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Two finite groups are called isocategorical if their categories of finite dimensional representations over a fixed field are equivalent as tensor categories.
I have two questions:

1. Is this definition valid for infinite groups? If yes can you please provide a reference for where is that defined.
2. if two infinite groups $G$ and $H$ have the same (isomorphic) Hopf algebra of representative functions, does this implies that $G$ and $H$ are isocategorical? Or what information we have about their categories of representations (equivalent, symmetrically equivalent...?)

If there is any reference for possible answers, provide it please, thanks.

Comment: What is the category of a group?  For (1), what does it mean to ask if a definition is valid?

Comment: By default, when considering a group as a category, people mean a groupoid with one object. But I don't see a natural tensor structure on it.

Comment: I think the OP probably means the category of finite-dimensional complex representations.

Comment: Sorry, i edited it, in fact a meant the cat rep(G) of f.d representations over a certain field. @LSpice by is the definition valid, i mean can we keep the same definition for infinite groups, i.e does it have sense and will be useful or we should adapt it somehow to have similar theory for say "isocategorical infinite groups"

Comment: The definition of "isocategorical" is awkward if it depends on the choice of field $K$. It should better be "$K$-isocategorical".

Comment: Can you give an example of two groups that are not isomorphic but are $K$-isocategorical?

Comment: @ArB arxiv.org/abs/math/0007196 A few other examples were obtained later, but I do not remember reference off the top of my head.

Comment: In the finite case, the problem is solved, as @Denis T mentioned in the paper arxiv.org/abs/math/0007196, that's why i'm asking for the infinite case. A trivial example is can be easily found, i.e of two non isomorphic infinite groups of the same category of representations (take any groups with only trivial finite dimensiinal reps e.g the Higman's group..). So can we have a non trivial example !!

Comment: This link might be useful: https://www.math.ru.nl/~mueger/PDF/Cordoba2009.pdf

Comment: Thank you @VictorOstrik , i had a look before at this paper, even i would like to stay at the abstract case rather than the topo compact one